# mutt error sending mail: gnutls_handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received

Tags: email, ssl, mutt, smtp, gnutls

I keep on getting an error as indicated by the title sending email in neomutt, This is what I put in my muttrc:

```
set from = "myemail@domain.ca"
set realname = "my name"

set smtp_url = "smtps://myemail@domain.ca@smtp-mail.outlook.com:587"
set smtp_pass = "pass"
set imap_pass = "pass"

set ssl_starttls = "yes"

set folder = "imaps://myemail@domain@outlook.office365.com:993"

set header_cache = "~/.mutt/cache/headers"
set message_chachedir = "~/.mutt/cache/bodies"
set certificate_file = "~/.mutt/certificates"

set editor = "vim"
```

So far I've tried changing my smtp url from smtps to smtp, but this only gave me the error "SASL authentication failed".

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> set smtp_url = "smtps://myemail@domain.ca@smtp-mail.outlook.com:587"
> ```

Port 587 is not smtps, but plain SMTP with optional upgrade to TLS using STARTTLS command. smtps is instead on port 465.

The *"unexpected TLS packet was received"* is the result of trying to interpret the non-TLS data (server welcome message) initially received on port 587 as TLS, which fails.